# Translate extrinsic rotations to intrinsic rotations ( Euler angles )

Tags: rotation, .net, opentk

The problem I have is very frustrating:
I am using the Jitter Physics library which gives Quaternion rotations, you can extract the extrinsic rotations but I need intrinsic rotations to rotate in OpenTK (There are other reasons as well so I don't want to make OpenTK use a Matrix)

```
GL.Rotate(xr, 1, 0, 0)
GL.Rotate(yr, 0, 1, 0)
GL.Rotate(zr, 0, 0, 1)
```

**EDIT : Response to the first answer**

```
Like This?

GL.Rotate(zr, 0, 0, 1)
GL.Rotate(yr, 0, 1, 0)
GL.Rotate(xr, 1, 0, 0)

Or This?

GL.Rotate(xr, 1, 0, 0)
GL.Rotate(yr, 0, 1, 0)
GL.Rotate(zr, 0, 0, 1)

GL.Rotate(zr, 0, 0, 1)
GL.Rotate(yr, 0, 1, 0)
GL.Rotate(xr, 1, 0, 0)

GL.Rotate(xr, 1, 0, 0)
GL.Rotate(yr, 0, 1, 0)
GL.Rotate(zr, 0, 0, 1)

I'm confused, please give an example
```

Comment: I've never heard of "extrinsic" and "intrinsic" rotations before.  Can you explain in more detail what you're looking for?

Comment: Euler angles are usually a bad idea unless you're using only two of the three or actually simulating gimbals. It might be helpful to explain why you think you need them.

Comment: IIRC Jitter uses a 3x3 matrix for rotation, not a quaternion. If you are getting a quaternion out of it, then `Matrix4.CreateFromQuaternion`, otherwise, you can shove the 3x3 matrix in the upper left of a Matrix4 and it'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way it seems is to plug the matrix into OpenTK Thanks for all the help though.

As to help any others with this problem this is the code

```
            GL.PushMatrix()

            Dim bim As Matrix4
            bim.M11 = Rotation(0)
            bim.M12 = Rotation(1)
            bim.M13 = Rotation(2)
            bim.M21 = Rotation(3)
            bim.M22 = Rotation(4)
            bim.M23 = Rotation(5)
            bim.M31 = Rotation(6)
            bim.M32 = Rotation(7)
            bim.M33 = Rotation(8)
            bim.M44 = 1
            bim = bim

            GL.PopMatrix()
            GL.PushMatrix()

            GL.MultMatrix(Matrix4.CreateTranslation(BlockPos(0) * 50, BlockPos(1) * 50, BlockPos(2) * 50))
            GL.MultMatrix(bim)
```

Answer (score 1):

So extrinsic rotation is generally meant to mean rotation around a fixed axis, while intrinsic rotation is rotation around a moving axis. In the former case the axes around which the rotation occurs are fixed in the spatial reference frame in which the object exists, whereas in the latter case it moves with the body.

You can verify it yourself that **rotations around the axes of a fixed coordinate frame in a certain order is the same as rotations around the axes of a moving coordinate frame in exactly the opposite order**. I suggest verifying this initially with some examples. I like a mug with a face on, but others have used textbooks or 3-legged dogs. Subsequently think how the rotation is applied around the axis in which the object is embedded at the start of its rotation and at its end.

This seems to suggest a very simple solution to your problem: *take the extrinsic rotation amounts and apply them in the opposite order* (thus using them as intrinsic rotations).

Comment: Please help with the edited code above, which displays my problem much better

Comment: You have asked which of the above approaches is correct. The first after the edit is correct, assuming that the "extrinsic rotations" you mention is indeed a series of 3 extrinsic rotations about spatial axes (as opposed to an angle-axis rotation, which is a different story). Perhaps you can give an example of how you obtain this extrinsic rotation so that one can be sure.

Comment: Out of the 3x3 matrix I get M11 M22 and M33

Comment: I don't think that will work. M11,M22 and M33 should not give you an extrinsic rotation or indeed any kind of rotation. I suggest you look to Robert Rouhani's answer and use the matrix directly and meanwhile, keep reading!